# How can i create a callback function in ASP.NET, which is called when database event is raised?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a notification system in ASP.NET which listens for a database event and send some info to number of devices.

This is a sample of the class that is responsible for catching the events:

```
    public class FbEventClass 
    {
        private static FbEventClass eventController = null;
        public static void CreateEventController(string connectionString)
        {
            if (eventController == null)
            {
                eventController = new FbEventClass(connectionString);
                eventController.AddListener(MessageListener);
            }
        }

        FbConnection connection;
        FbRemoteEvent revent;

        public FbEventClass(string connectionString)
        {
            connection = new FbConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            revent = new FbRemoteEvent(connection);
            revent.AddEvents(String[] { "TEST" });
        }

        public static void MessageListener(object sender, FbRemoteEventEventArgs e)
        {
            SendNotification("Message recieved");
        } 
    }
```

I create the static object from a controller:

```
FbEventClass.CreateEventController(dt.connectionString);
```

The problem is that the MessageListener() method is never called. If i call the controller again, the object is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to find an answer. It may not be the perfect solution, but it works for me. I just added CreateEventController() into a thread.

```
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
  {
      FbEventClass.CreateEventController(cc);
  });
```